# Angular 5 & Django REST - Issue uploading files

Tags: django, angular, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I developed an Angular application where the user can handle brands.

When creating/updating a brand, the user can also upload a logo. All data are sent to the DB via a REST API built using the Django REST Framework.

Using the Django REST Framework API website I'm able to upload files, but using Angular when I send data thu the API I get an error.
I also tried to encode the File object to base64 using FileReader, but I get the same error from Django.

Can you help me understanding the issue?

**Models**:

```
export class Brand {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    is_active: boolean = true;
    is_customer_brand: boolean = false;
    logo_img: Image;
}

export class Image {
    id: number;
    img: string; // URL path to the image (full size)
    img_md: string; // medium size
    img_sm: string; // small
    img_xs: string; // extra-small/thumbnail
}
```

**Service**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { Brand } from './brand';

const endpoint = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/brands/'

@Injectable()
export class BrandService {

  private brands: Array<Brand>;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  list(): Observable<Array<Brand>> {
    return this.http.get(endpoint)
        .map(response => {
        this.brands = response.json() as Brand[];
        return response.json();
      })
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  create(brand: Brand): Observable<Brand> {
    console.log(brand);
    return this.http.post(endpoint+'create/', brand)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  get(id): Observable<Brand> {
    return this.http.get(endpoint+id)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error:any, caught:any): any {
    console.log(error, caught);
  }

}
```

Error from the browser console:

> "{"logo_img":{"img":["The submitted data was not a file. Check the
>   encoding type on the form."]}}"

[image: Angular Error]

**Django Serializer**:

```
class BrandSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    is_active = BooleanField(required=False)
    logo_img = ImageSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Brand
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'description',
            'is_active',
            'is_customer_brand',
            'logo_img',
        ]

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        image = validated_data.get('logo_img',None)
        old_image = None
        if image:
            image = image.get('img',None)
            brand_str = validated_data['name'].lower().replace(' ','-')
            ext = validated_data['logo_img']['img'].name.split('.')[-1].lower()
            filename = '{0}.{1}'.format(brand_str,ext)
            user = None
            request = self.context.get('request')
            if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
                user = request.user
            image_serializer_class = create_image_serializer(path='logos', filename=filename, created_by=user, img_config = {'max_w':3000.0,'max_h':3000.0,'max_file_size':1.5,'to_jpeg':False})
            image_serializer = image_serializer_class(data=validated_data['logo_img'])
            image_serializer.is_valid()
            validated_data['logo_img'] = image_serializer.save()
            old_image = instance.logo_img
        super(BrandSerializer, self).update(instance,validated_data)
        if old_image: # Removing old logo
            old_image.img.delete()
            old_image.img_md.delete()
            old_image.img_sm.delete()
            old_image.img_xs.delete()
            old_image.delete()
        return instance

    def create(self, validated_data):
        image = validated_data.get('logo_img',None)
        print(image)
        if image:
            print(image)
            image = image.get('img',None)
            print(image)
            brand_str = validated_data['name'].lower().replace(' ','-')
            ext = validated_data['logo_img']['img'].name.split('.')[-1].lower()
            filename = '{0}.{1}'.format(brand_str,ext)
            user = None
            request = self.context.get('request')
            if request and hasattr(request, 'user'):
                user = request.user
            image_serializer_class = create_image_serializer(path='logos', filename=filename, created_by=user, img_config = {'max_w':3000.0,'max_h':3000.0,'max_file_size':1.5,'to_jpeg':False})
            image_serializer = image_serializer_class(data=validated_data['logo_img'])
            image_serializer.is_valid()
            validated_data['logo_img'] = image_serializer.save()
        return super(BrandSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting a new brand to the server with files, I have three main choices:

- Base64 encode the file, at the expense of increasing the data size by around 33%.
- Send the file first in a multipart/form-data POST, and return an ID to the client. The client then sends the metadata with the ID, and the server re-associates the file and the metadata.
- Send the metadata first, and return an ID to the client. The client then sends the file with the ID, and the server re-associates the file and the metadata.

The Base64 encoding will involve unacceptable payload.
So I choose to use multipart/form-data.

Here's how I implemented it in Angular's service:

```
create(brand: Brand): Observable<Brand> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    let formData = new FormData(); // Note: FormData values can only be string or File/Blob objects
    Object.entries(brand).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (key === 'logo_img') { 
        formData.append('logo_img_file', value.img);
      } else {
        formData.append(key, value);
    });
    return this.http.post(endpoint+'create/', formData)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: Since there's no way to have nested fields using `FormData`, I cannot append `formData.append('logo_img', {'img' : FILE_OBJ })`. I had change the API in order to receive the file in one field called `logo_img_file`.

Hope that my issue helped someone.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. In my scenario, I have to upload only one image.  I am quite not clear with this approach, you mean to say submit two separate forms?  Is there a working example?

Comment: I tried adding this line to see if it resolves the issue. It made it more worse.------------
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;');-------------headers were passed as params for post request call.